# better way to write this mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently using this type of mod_rewrite code for all my page...but i think its too long. There must be a shorter way of writing same code? and does it increase any kind of load on he server?

```
RewriteRule ^Login/$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login/$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^Login$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
```

the first line is for normal url - "http://website/Login/"
second one is if the user doesn't type the capital "L" - "http://website/login/"
third one is if he doesn't add an ending slash on the first url - "http://website/Login"
fourth one is if he doesn't add an ending slash on the second url - "http://website/login"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[Ll]ogin/?$
```

[Ll] matches either L or l, question mark means the previous character (slash) is optional.

Answer (score 2):

Further to @milan's answer, you could also specify the `NC` flag, of which makes the rewrite rule not case sensitive.

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC,L]
```

[Reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc)

Comment: That wouldn't match exactly what the previous rules did, however. (It would match more, like LoGiN.)

Comment: If that's a problem then the author of this question has far greater issues. If one is worried about the spelling of a URL that much, simply only allow lower case.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^[Ll]ogin/?$ login.php [L]
```

But I must ask, why?? Why not simply choose one URL and stick with it? Do you expect people to enter the URL manually?

Comment: no its not that.i can stick with one url.but i can't trust the visitors/users are going to stick to one.i have experienced such problems with the previous version on my site and don't want to repeat the same in this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [L,NC]
```

Should do it. NC is for case insensitivity and ? makes the slash optional.